# MPMoviePlayerController load half of the screen when internet is slow

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, mpmovieplayercontroller

I a using `MPMoviePlayerController` for stream play in my application. When there is slow internet connection, it loads after very long time however it loads the player in half of the screen instead of `self.view.bounds` and it starts playback with black screen.

The time elapsed is running however I get black screen however controls are still there.

```
var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "movieurl")!
self.moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController()
self.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.Streaming
self.moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
self.moviePlayer.prepareToPlay()
self.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = true
self.moviePlayer.stop()
self.moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.bounds
self.view.addSubview(self.moviePlayer.view)
self.moviePlayer.fullscreen = true
self.moviePlayer.setFullscreen(true, animated: true)
self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Embedded
self.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.AspectFit
self.moviePlayer.play()
```

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout?

Comment: No, its a simple view controller where I am adding mpmovieplayercontroller programatically. Its coming when the internet connection is slow!!

Comment: there is no dependency b/w view size and internet speed

Comment: why its coming and sometime it shows blank screen too

Comment: @Suhailkalathil...is there anything I am missing !!!